# how to do search between two dates from date and to date using low search in expressionengine

Tags: channel-entries, search, low-search, entries, date

I'm not getting the expected results with low search range.
Here is my search form

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="press_releases" required="keywords" result_page="/communications/result"}
<fieldset>
<label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
<input name="range-from:entry_date" value="2014-01-01">
<input name="range-to:entry_date" value="2014-01-24">
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Search Result Code:

```
{exp:low_search:results status="not closed" query="{segment_3}" disable="member_data|category_fields"}
{if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
<li><a href="{path='communications/view'}/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
{if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
{if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

How i can handle this with low search using range?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the [Range filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#ranges) only targets custom channel fields. If you want to target the entry_date, you can use the native [start_on and stop_before parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on). If you do, make sure the values are formatted as stated in the EE docs, so something like:

```
<input name="start_on" value="2014-01-01 00:00">
<input name="stop_before" value="2014-01-24 23:59">
```